# How do I provide a file path in Mac OS X while creating a file in Java?

Tags: java, macos, file, creation

```
File f = new File("C:\\Temp\\Example.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

On executing, a new file named "Example.txt" will be created in the `Temp` folder. How do I provide the file path in Mac OS X?

I tried providing:

```
File f = new File("\\Users\\pavankumar\\Desktop\\Testing\\Java.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

But it didn't work for me.

Comment: Any one working in MAC OSX please comment below..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Forward slash "/" must be used to get the file path here.
Use:

```
File f = new File("/Users/pavankumar/Desktop/Testing/Java.txt");
f.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 23):

Please use Java's built-in `File.separator` to be independent from the OS, like this:

```
String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
File f = new File(home + File.separator + "Desktop" + File.separator + "Testing" + File.separator + "Java.txt");
```

Or use the static utility-method `FilenameUtils.normalize` (from library and package `org.apache.commons.io`):

```
File f = new File(FileNameUtils.normalize(home + "/Desktop/Testing/Java.txt"));
```

Either of them can be used; the second option needs the external library [Apache Commons IO](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/).

Comment: Ah yes sure. System.getProperty("user.home") would be correct. Updated the answer.

Comment: for the latest commons.io dependency, it is `FilenameUtils.normalize(String filename)`.

Answer (score 4):

On Linux, Mac OS X and other *nix flavours, the folder separator is `/` not `\`, so there isn't any need to escape anything, `some/path/of/folders`.

Also, you can use the `/tmp` folder for your temporary files.

Finally, on *nix systems, the home directory is usually represented by `~` or is in the environment variable `HOME`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a `File.separator` system-dependent constant that you should use to provide some portability to your Java code.

Answer (score 0):

For the relative file path in macos from the Users directory you can use $Home.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

In Mac OS This is working in below fashion, please try with
File f = new File("/Users/bsingh/Desktop/Write/myTextFile.txt");

Comment: This has already been mentioned in the other answers. *When answering older questions that already have answers, please make sure you provide either a novel solution or a significantly better explanation than existing answers.*