# Java System.getProperty(“user.dir”) on Mac OS X getting exception

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I tried like below in Mac

```
Sheet guru99Sheet = file.readExcel(System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//", "//TestCase.xlsx" , "KeywordFramework");
```

This is my exact file path

```
/Users/anakin/Documents/workspace/KeywordDriven/TestCase.xlsx
```

but when I ran it in selenium I got the exception below.

```
/Users/anakin/Documents/workspace/KeywordDriven/\/TestCase.xlsx(No such file or directory)
```

Can anyone please help me on this how to set path on Mac

Comment: Where did you put your excel file it is in any folder? or directly you put on a project?

Comment: in my project .

Comment: "user.home" instead of "user.dir" use this as reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30120813/how-to-provide-file-path-in-mac-os-x-while-creating-a-file-in-java/30120987#30120987